How can I check if a device is supported by Linux?
I want to use the ax200 wifi module by Intel in the imx8qm board. Since I am new in Linux, I have difficulty finding the right documentation.
Where should I search for it?

Every device has VEN (Vendor ID) and DEV (Device ID) which you can get via lspci -nn or lsusb depending on a bus, and then you can:

Check https://linux-hardware.org/ e.g. https://linux-hardware.org/?id=pci:14c3-0616-105b-e0cd

Grep through Linux kernel sources



Ideally if possible, you obtain the device to test it, you load any Live Linux distribution and check whether everything works. Unfortunately that's not always possible.
Intel is an open source friendly company, so normally all their devices are well supported in Linux, including yours.

+1. Also, the i.MX8 board will be very hard to sell if it contained software not supported by Linux, the operating system NXP advertises the i.MX series for.
